# Read process memory in C

Tags: c, windows

I try to read from process memory that I wrote, my code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void main()
 {
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);
    x = y;
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d",x);
    scanf("%d",&y);
 }
```

ok, i finded the adress in Cheat engine, and success editing and so on,
i search in google for like 5 hours at least, find alot of codes, cant understand them, i mean. the code that does work, run even when the process is off -_-' 
can someone help me to build a typical code that read value from adresss in memory?

Answer (score 3):

As the platform is Windows, see the WINAPI function [ReadProcessMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The posted code is reading from standard input and writing to standard output, it is not attempting to read memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not doing anything that even resembles what you speak about in the question text, making this very confusing.

In most modern operating systems that implement [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [memory protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), you cannot easily read other processes' memory.

Even if you have one process print out the address of one of its variables, that address is *virtual*, so if your process tries to access memory at the same virtual address it will *not* access the same physical memory.